# JS Files Not Loading In Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to write a Chrome App. I have multiple JS files that I use in the app which are included in the head like so:

```
    <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/menu.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/contacts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/profile.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/reminder.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="surgery_.js"></script>-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/riskcalculator.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="profile.js"></script>          -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tempStyle.css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
```

When I run the app in the browser, this works fine. But when I try to run this as a Chrome App, the JS files don't seem to get loaded. At least, they don't seem to work. Please let me know where the problem lies.

Thanks and regards...

Comment: What would you hope we can tell you from what you've given? Your HTML is technically correct. Have you attempted debugging or viewed console output (logs)?

Comment: Off topic: You don't need `type` attributes for defautl types (JavaScript, CSS) with HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can’t reference any external resources in any of your app files (except for video and audio resources). You can’t embed external resources in an iframe.

See [Chrome apps -> Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy) for a complete list of restrictions.

**Solution:** include all files in the app package.

Comment: Thanks very much - that turned out to be precisely the issue.